# Android SQLite Adding User Defined Table Names to a Pre Made Database

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my first post so forgive me if I've done anything wrong. I have a database in my assets folder that I bring into my app on start up, I can then make a new table by running this code in the onUpgrade (as long as the versions don't match).

```
if(oldVersion < 2){ db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + WorkoutsList.DATABASE_TABLE_DYNAMIC + " (" +
                    WorkoutsDBAdapter.WORKOUTS_ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    WorkoutsDBAdapter.WORKOUTS_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    WorkoutsDBAdapter.WORKOUTS_WEIGHT + " DECIMAL NOT NULL, "+
                    WorkoutsDBAdapter.WORKOUTS_SETS + " INT NOT NULL, "+
                    WorkoutsDBAdapter.WORKOUTS_REPS + " INT NOT NULL);");}
```

I run this code by clicking on a button

```
    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String table = tableName.getText().toString();
            DATABASE_TABLE_DYNAMIC = table;
            if (table.trim().length() > 0) {
            DbHelper.addTable();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter table name",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    });
```

DbHelper.addTable(); simply increments the database version by 1. (it used to do something else that's why the name is miss leading). Is it possible to get onUpgrade to run as soon as the button is pressed (as soon as DbHelper.addTable(); is run, because right now my database only updates once I view the information using another method) Any feedback on my method of doing it and any other ways you would recommend would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to this. Thanks!

Comment: `onUpgrade()` is called when you initialize the `SQLiteOpenHelper` with a new version. Have you done that ?

Comment: Yeah i did that and then ran the .open and .close methods and it seems to be updating, that was very simple hehe :D

Comment: ok. I'll move my comment to the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onUpgrade()` is called when you initialize the SQLiteOpenHelper with a new version.